# Phonegap and Adobe Edge

Tags: cordova, adobe-edge

Been playing around with Adobe Edge, and its a pretty cool product. However, when I try to phonegap the animations it doesn't work. Has anyone found success in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck targeting the animation using this code after you're sure that your stage element is loaded and in place:

```
var stageID = 'EDGE-ID-Name'; 
$.Edge.getComposition(stageID).symbolInstances[0].play(0);
```

where stageID is the name of the animation given at the end of the edgePreload.js file.